# chechbox checked if value exist in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I try to select checkbox based on value get from database already inserted using implode so the value inserted in database with separator, but when I show form with selected value it selects nothing

```
//getting from DB
 $moteur=$row['moteur'];
$moteur= explode(",",$moteur);

try to select 

<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="Vidange" 
<?php
$count=count($moteur);
for( $i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 echo ($moteur[$i]=='Vidange' ? 'checked' : 'disabled'); ?> >

         </th>
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="nv" 
<?php
for( $i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 echo ($moteur[$i]=='nv' ? 'checked' : 'disabled'); ?> >

             </th>
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="remplace" 
<?php
for( $i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 echo ($moteur[$i]=='remplace' ? 'checked' : 'disabled'); ?> >
         </th>
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="nettoye" 
<?php
for( $i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 echo ($moteur[$i]=='nettoye' ? 'checked' : 'disabled'); ?> >



         </th>
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="effectue"

<?php
for( $i=0;$i<$count;$i++)

echo ($moteur[$i]=='effectue' ? 'checked' : 'disabled'); ?> >        </th>
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="controle" 
<?php
for( $i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 echo ($moteur[$i]=='controle' ? 'checked' : 'disabled'); ?> >      
         </th>
```

Comment: Can you like, clean up the code so it is more readable?

Comment: try var_dump($moteur); and check what kind of values are you getting and correct according to that

Comment: what $moteur contains. Do you want to make checkboxs on the basis of $moteur.

Comment: your question is not clear as your post

Comment: grammatical changes

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox values are stored as 1 or 0 (unless you have manually changed this). You are comparing against the value you have set yourself. This will not work.

I cannot tell from this snippet if you are manipulating the form data before save, given you never mentioned it i would assume not.

Compare the input name against values 1 or 0 to toggle the 'checked' state.

Answer (score 0):

what I am understand from your question, try this simple snippet

```
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="Vidange" <?php echo (in_array('Vidange',$moteur))? 'checked' : 'disabled' ?> ></th>
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="nv"  <?php echo (in_array('nv',$moteur))? 'checked' : 'disabled' ?> > </th>
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="remplace" <?php echo (in_array('remplace',$moteur))? 'checked' : 'disabled' ?> ></th>
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="nettoye" <?php echo (in_array('nettoye',$moteur))? 'checked' : 'disabled' ?> ></th>
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="effectue" <?php echo (in_array('effectue',$moteur))? 'checked' : 'disabled' ?> > </th>
<th> <input type="checkbox" name="moteur[]" value="controle" <?php echo (in_array('controle',$moteur))? 'checked' : 'disabled' ?> ></th>
```